# Not able to convert google-api-services-admin-directory Organizations To JSONArray. Because of customType value is missing

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm not able to convert a `google-api-services-admin-directory Organization` to JSONArray, as the following exception is thrown:

> Exception message : Missing value at character 38

I have this code:

```
Get user = directoryService.users().get("mangesh@domain.in");

User domainUserObj = user.execute();

logger.warning("Organizations "+domainUserObj.getOrganizations());

JSONArray userOrgJsonArr = new JSONArray(domainUserObj.getOrganizations().toString());

logger.warning("Organizations-JsonArr "+userOrgJsonArr);
```

And I get the data from the API like this

> Organizations [{title=Dev, primary=true, customType=, department=R&D,
>   description=Permanant, costCenter=Cost Test 12}]

The **JAR** version that I used is  **google-api-services-admin-directory-directory_v1-rev72-1.22.0.jar**

Complete Exception Stack trace

Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.ApiTestServelet doGet
*WARNING: Organizations [{title=Dev, primary=true, **customType=**, department=R&D, description=Permanant, costCenter=Cost Test 12}]*

> Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler
>   **WARNING: Exception message : Missing value at character 38** Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler
>   WARNING: Error in class ApiTestServelet Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM
>   com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:410) Jul 26, 2018
>   7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler
>   WARNING:    org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:369) Jul
>   26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:205) Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52
>   PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:344) Jul 26, 2018
>   7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler
>   WARNING:    org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:125) Jul 26, 2018
>   7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler
>   WARNING:    org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:157) Jul 26, 2018
>   7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler
>   WARNING:
>   com.company.project.ApiTestServelet.doGet(ApiTestServelet.java:122)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) Jul 26,
>   2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler
>   WARNING:
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) Jul 26,
>   2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler
>   WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   com.company.project.filter.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:69) Jul
>   26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:72)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:44)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52
>   PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547) Jul 26,
>   2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler
>   WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212) Jul
>   26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) Jul
>   26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>   Jul 26, 2018 7:57:52 PM com.company.project.utility.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler WARNING:
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution, which is to use `com.google.api.client.util.ArrayMap` to iterate the data.

But I don't understand why `customType` is coming empty from the API.

```
ArrayList orgArrList = (java.util.ArrayList)domainUserObj.getOrganizations();

for(int i = 0 ; i < orgArrList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("For getOrganizations ::"+orgArrList.get(i));                
    ArrayMap<String,String> orgMapArr = (ArrayMap<String, String>)
                                         orgArrList.get(i);
    System.out.println("ArrayMap-UserOrganization ::"+orgMapArr);           
    for(int index=0; index < orgMapArr.size();index++) {
    try {
        System.out.println(orgMapArr.getKey(index) + " "
                                   + orgMapArr.getValue(index));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Output :

> For getOrganizations ::{title=Dev, primary=true, customType=,
>    department=R&D, description=Permanant, costCenter=Cost Test 12}
>
> ArrayMap-UserOrganization ::{title=Dev, primary=true, customType=,
>    department=R&D, description=Permanant, costCenter=Cost Test 12}
>
> title Dev java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>    customType  department R&D description Permanant costCenter Cost Test
>    12

Comment: Would you mind accepting your own answer? For future reference of the community, of course. I believe you have to wait two days for that.